# How do I specify all files on drive with Java?

Tags: java

I want to know all the paths to the filenames on the drive with Java.

For example, if I run it, it would show:

/MyDoc2017-12-04.txt

/system/system.img

/system/kernel.img

/pizzaplaces/pizzaplaces.txt

or C:/myDoc blah blah blah.

Something like that.

Could I do that using a for statement?

Thanks

Ashland.

Answer (score 2):

This is little method that does that. All you have to do is:

```
File root = new File("your partition root absolute path");
getAllFilesPath(root);

private static void getAllFilesPath(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isFile()) {
                        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        getAllFilesPath(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't recurse

Comment: Thank you but I would like to do it with subdirectories please.

Comment: Np, could you mark it as solution, so others can see if needed :)